# django: rest-auth and allauth for Facebook registration API requires CSRF token

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

Using `allauth` and `django-rest-auth` to create a facebook login api. I've followed the both packages documentations and using example from [rest-auth doc](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#social-authentication-optional). I've followed all the steps and I can successfully use this API from DRF browse-able API view and it is successfully performing the registration. When I try this API from somewhere else like postman it asks for CSRF token.
I tried to use `csrf_exempt` decorator but that doesn't seem to be effective on this url.

Here is my url config:

```
url(r'^rest-auth/facebook/$', csrf_exempt(FacebookLogin.as_view()), name='fb_login'),
```

Rest of the things are same as they mentioned in the documentation for `django-rest-auth`.

I can't figure out what am I missing, or where should I look for a fix. Any help to diagnose the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR Set `authentication_classes = ()` in your `FacebookLogin` view.

The login and register views are supposed to have no authentication checks. I assume you have your DRF `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` set to token auth and session auth in the order. So when your request is processing the server doesn't find auth token so as a fallback it tries to do session auth which requires CSRF which inturn causes the CSRF failure.

Comment: This is quite simple solution. I didn't get it this way so fixed it little longer way by allowing requests from anybody. Which is actually the same thing as you mentioned.

Comment: I am having another issue. Maybe you might have an idea. Token generated this way(social login) is not being authenticated when I send it in header. But the traditional user's token is authenticating when sent with request. Any idea whats wrong? @Sagar

Comment: Yes. The social login token is not used for your app login. It is just to map your app user account to fb user account.

Comment: I am not talking about facebook `access_token`. When it is successfully logged in/registered into the system then you get `token` in response which is supposed to be used for JWT authentication. That token is not working.

Comment: One strange thing that I noticed if I set its username, which is not set by default on social login, then token from same request seems to work fine. Any idea how to overcome this behavior?

Comment: Can't think of any reasons. Looking at how your user model and all auth settings are configured might give some idea. May be try adding a new question with those details. I will try looking into it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46982435/django-allauth-and-rest-auth-facebook-login-token-does-not-work-with-jwt-authe